# Is a resistor capacitor model of a battery a good approximation?

Tags: batteries, capacitance, modeling

Batteries are known to have an amount of internal resistance that reduces their terminal voltage with current draw. However another property of batteries appears to be the gradual recovery of the terminal voltage when load is eliminated. It seems that the following is a good characterisation of a real battery. Is it used in electrical engineering? Is there a standard/accepted calibration technique for it?

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fit4U0.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

Comment: There can be no answer as **it depends**, it depends on what you want to do with this model. For some situations the model will be "good enough", for other situations it will be **unusable**. I suggest that you first ask yourself what properties of the battery need to be modelled for your purpose and how accurate that needs to be. And "very accurate" or "somewhat accurate" **means nothing**, you need to put a **number** on that, like: up to 20% off is OK.

Comment: They are usually more complex than that. Try this: https://www.google.com/search?rlz=1C1CHBF_en-GBGB908GB908&sxsrf=ALeKk02_VcgLN8_MKrThscbLQ_7rU9CDuQ:1615299371352&source=univ&tbm=isch&q=equivalent+circuit+of+a+battery&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwjauPCJs6PvAhVimVwKHUZwBpkQjJkEegQIAhAB&biw=1342&bih=722

Comment: For many purposes it'll be fine. It's most likely not good enough for testing a battery charger for a chemistry that requires a complex charging algorithm. If you have a practical reason for asking, edit the question to add more detail.

Comment: Depends on your needs. My first order simplified model would be a capacitor in the kF range with series resistance as your model have.

Comment: I suppose 'good' is one where the mathematical model of the components is physically representative of the whole. I'm fairly sure the physics governing the recovery is not capacitive, but it might well enforce a very similar voltage/current behaviour. Or it might be totally different.

Comment: The effect you're talking about is related to the depletion of reactants at the electrode surfaces, and how fast ions can migrate through the electrolyte to replenish them. Obviously, this is a strong function of things like battery chemistry, physical construction and temperature. At the very least, you need a second resistor between the capacitor and the load.

Comment: Batteries do not behave like they have a capacitor of any size across the output terminals  (maybe xx pF range). It's usually necessary to put a capacitor across the battery to reduce the impedance when using it to power circuits without a regulator. For example, an audio amplifier or  transistor radio. Modeling the chemical effects in relaxation would require a huge capacitor.

Comment: @DaveTweed A second resistor in series with the capacitor controlling its recharge rate?

Comment: No, I said "between the capacitor and the load", and that's what I meant. It limits the discharge current and also prevents the capacitor from discharging fully into a dead short.